# Change mongodb Criteria content in spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, criteria

So I have a `Criteria` for `mongodb` constructed and I want to check the content of it, and change it if needed. I couldn't find anyway how to do that.
To be more precise, I wanna know which fields are included and which values are there and change them based on some logic.

Comment: To get `key:value` pair use [.getCriteriaObject()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/CriteriaDefinition.html)

Comment: not what I need, it will return operator and so on, I just need the actual value without `$in` or `$or` etc

Comment: I guess it's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Answering my own question:
In order to achieve the above you need a piece of code like this

```
final Document document = (Document) filterCriteria.getCriteriaObject().get(whatever request param you need)

Collection<ObjectId> ids = (Collection<ObjectId>) document.values().stream().getwhateverIdsOrParams you need.
```

I hope this helps somebody.